# how to iterate over arrays ini18next translation ejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ejs, i18next

I have implemeneted the translation using i18next, 
https://github.com/i18next/i18next 
I am trying to iterate over nested arrays in front end , But not working in the translation mode,https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/objects-and-arrays please help

en.json

```
{
  "title": "List of Countries",
  "list":[{
     "name": "Singapore",
     "code": "SG"
  },{
    "name": "Thailand",
    "code": "TH"
 }]
}
```

index.ejs

```
<h2><%=t("list.0.name")%></h2> //working fine

//using map not working

<% t("list").map(e=>{%>
  <a href="#"><%=t(e.name)%></a>
<%})%>
```

Comment: How is it _"not working"_?

Comment: @Phil am getting the following error 
`cannot read property 'map' of undefined`